# Как вытянуть значение из php с ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

**Кратко о всем:**

1. Хотел удалять записи без перезагрузки страницы. Решил использовать `Ajax`.
2. При написании возникла проблема, конкретно:

   - Если же у меня записи из БД выводятся в цикле, то как мне вытянуть *`ID`* (значение поля с названием `id`) того этапа цикла, где как раз был этот **ИД** (где я нажал на кнопку с классом `.del`.
     Пробовал поставить **аякс-скрипт** внутрь цикла, но понял, что идея плохая, т.к. этот самый `js-скрипт` будет миллион раз повторятся.

Есть такой код:

```
<?php
     $pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=awesome;host=localhost", "main", "main");

     $sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
     $rs = $pdo->query($sql);

     while($row = $rs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
?>
     <div class="col-md-12">
         <h1><?php echo $row['title']?></h1>
         <h3><?php echo $row['text']?></h3>
         <p>Автор: <?php echo $row['author']?></p>
         <p><?php echo $row['time']?></p>
         <br><br>
         <a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']?>">Редагувати</a>
         <a class="btn btn-danger del">Видалити</a>
         <hr>
     </div>

<? } ?>
```

И сам **аякс**:

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var id = <?php echo $row['id']; ?>;
                console.log(id);
                $(".del").bind("click",function(){
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'delete.php?id=',
                        type: 'GET',
                        data: ({id: id})
                    });  
                });
            });
</script>
```

В файле `delete.php` вот такой код:

```
<?php
            $pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=awesome;host=localhost", "main", "main");
            $id = $_GET['id'];
            $sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id='$id'";
            $pdo->query($sql);

            echo '
                <p>Успішно видалено!</p>
                <br>
                <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-default">Назад<a>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну так добавьте ваш 'id' в доступном для JS виде в сам элемент как вы делаете для редактирования. Например так:

```
<a class="btn btn-danger del" data-id=<?php echo $row['id']?>>Видалити</a>
```

А дальше получите его в скрипте:

```
$('.del').bind('click', function(evtObject) {
  var elem = evtObject.target;
  $.ajax({
        url: 'delete.php?id=',
        type: 'GET',
        data: ({id: elem.dataset.id })
    }).done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
        elem.parentNode.remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: Ооо, то что надо! Спасибо!

Comment: Но у меня с ajax-запросом что-то неладное, `div` не хочет исчезать, только после перезагрузки..

Comment: Даже не так, как мне сделать удаление записи? С `БД` оно удалило, но как это устроить в `DOM`?

Comment: С чего вы решили, что ajax запрос будет автоматом модифицировать ваш DOM? Так же при успешном завершении запроса через JS и правите как вам нужно. См. обновлённый пример.

Comment: в том то и фишка..но спасибо)